# Group by not able to create query

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

my records in table **LOCATION**

```
id area
1 bangalore
2 mysore
3 bangalore
etc...,
```

I need to query in the table where I should get the last 15 records of each area and I'm not knowing upfront about the areas available in the table.

tried grouping but that didn't work.

Comment: Please show what you tried and explain how it "didn't work".

Answer (score 0):

If the "last 15 records" means the largest `id` values, then `row_number()` is one method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by area order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 15;
```

Comment: I'm new to SQL checking the solution..once I found it's working will accept the solution...

Comment: I'm getting this error using MySQL workbench https://pasteboard.co/Jgz1S33.jpg